# PhoneGap + Sencha2 screen blank

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've started a project in PhoneGap which will utilise Sencha Touch 2.

I tried to change the app name from 'app', since  I've heard that conflicts with PhoneGap on Android devices. I altered `app.js` to `main.js` and that worked, but then I tried changing the `Ext.application.name`. All I got was a white screen after the loading splash, even with the old name `Sencha`. [Debug console](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) shows nothing at all happening, and the document `<body>` was empty. This happens with both `sencha-touch-all.js` and `sencha-touch-all-debug.js`. Test device is an iPad 1G running `iOS 4.3.5`.

---

Aside: To debug this issue, I set up [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) on my Mac and added the appropriate `<script>` tag to `index.html`. After making that change, though, the app didn't even launch. It hung on the PhoneGap splash png and I got this message from `gdb-remote`:

```
error: failed to launch '<app URI>' -- failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet
```

The only reference to that message besides its definition in gdb-remote source that I can find is [here](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2010/06/lldb-new-debugger-on-mac-os-x.html), and it's unrelated. I managed to get the issue to go away by restarting the iPad and removing build intermediates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The issue here was a missing value in the Ext.application definition (key with no associated value), so the whole app definition probably tanked as a result of that. Hence blank screen.